# What's wrong with this code? TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: list, python-2.7, floating-point

In this program, i want marks of 3 subjects per each student, for 4 students.
But when i run this one, i get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\Python\Lab\Lab6_3.py", line 12, in <module>
    for marks in marks[student]:
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I can't identify what's wrong with, using the len() function to find the number of elements in  a list.
Here's the code:

```
while True:
    try:
        marks=[]
        print "Enter marks of the 3 subjects of each student : "
        for student in range(4):
            marks.append(raw_input())
            marks[student]=map(float,marks[student].split(" "))
            if len(marks[student])!=3:
                print "Please enter marks of 3 subjects per each student"
        for student in range(4):
            total=0
            for marks in marks[student]:
                if marks<0:
                    print "You have entered a minus value"
                total+=marks
            print "Total of student %d = %f" %((student+1),total)
        break
    #except TypeError:
    #    print "You have entered an invalid input1"
    except ValueError:
        print "You have entered an invalid input2"
    except NameError:
        print "You have entered an invalid input3"
    except SyntaxError:
        print "You have entered an invalid input4"
    else:
        print "DONE !\n"
```

Here, I have skipped the exception "TypeError" to identify the fault. Can anybody tell what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`marks` is only an iterable the first time through the outer loop. Since `marks` is *also* the name you use in the inner loop, the iterable no longer exists in the outer loop.

TL;DR: `for` loops don't create a new scope in Python.

Comment: yes, Thanks dude! But what do you mean by creating a **new scope** in a **for** loop ?

Comment: In C-like languages, [blocks create a new scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope). In Python, they don't.